# Zxing via intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, zxing

In my application I use the zxing library. I start de zxing barcodescanner via intent. But when the user has no barcodescanner installed. The application stops working. How can I check if a zxing barcodescanner is already installed?

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to start the zxing application?

Comment: My code to start the barcodescanner is not important. Vipul Shah solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

There's a page on the zxing wiki that explicitly mentions this case:

> ### [How to scan a barcode from another Android application via Intents](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent)
>
> The best way to integrate is to use the small library of code we have provided. It correctly handles for you many details, such as setting category, flags, picking the most appropriate app, and ***most importantly handling the case where Barcode Scanner is not installed***.