# ZXing scan by intent, download app without scanning

Tags: android, zxing

I'm writing an app that uses ZXing. It's used in an area where there isn't good wireless or mobile coverage, so I'd like to prompt users to download zxing at the same time as downloading my app, but well before they actually do a scan. Can I call the ZXing IntentIntegrator to download ZXing if it isn't installed, but then not actually do a scan afterwards?

And, without actually performing a scan, what's the approved way to check if ZXing is already installed? Or do I simply do that as described [in this other StackOverview answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066733/zxing-via-intent), without using the IntentIntegrator code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`IntentIntegrator` source](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java). Basically, you could fork the code and add a function that just checks whether Barcode Scanner or a compatible app is installed and if not, displays the download dialog:

```
String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
if (targetAppPackage == null) {
  return showDownloadDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll just modify the source I use then.