# How correctly manage the First ZXING Intent?

Tags: android

I have implemented the ZXing functionnality in my App to read QR-Code.
Xzing runs with Barcode scanner via an exmplicit intent so the first you initiate the intent, it will ask to install barcode.

So it redirect you to the Play Store and the application gets installed.

Anyway, there is something not really easy to manage here as the Intent has been launched but we never get a return.

So the application waits for ever....

Is there any event to intercept or something like that...

Maybe there an OnActivity result for barcode installation already in the Integrator?

I tried to first deal with the PackageManager according to what is said here [Zxing via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066733/zxing-via-intent)
But in fact the test list.size() is successfull for ... Zalando    Arghhh!!!

What happens?

The goal was to check if BarCode is installed, if no, ask for install it with a StartActivityForResult and once the install is complete, launch the Scan Intent.

Regards,

Comment: Could be nice to explain a little bit why you downgrade it !

Comment: Ok no problem, I switch to Zbar, for those who wants to directly integrate a bar code reader in their application because despite Sean Owen thinks, there are good reason to do that way, Zbar is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
It's a pity I don't have an answer to my question because I wonder in fact if it's no more common than only using Xzing.
The actual prefered Xzing implementation seems to be to use an intent to launch the barCode Scanner application.
The problem occurs if BarCode Scanner is not yet installed on your device.
In that case, the intent launch the play store to let you download it.
Here is the problem because, unless I didn't understand something and as I didn't get an answer, I think I'm not wrong, once BarCode Scanner is downloaded, installed and launched, you don't receive any answer to your sent Intent! Letting your user the ass between two chairs.

Another alternative could be to deal first with the package manager to ask it if Barcode Scanner is installed. That way, you discuss with the package manager to install the app and then launch your scan intent.
Unfortunately, I also tried that but for a reason I didn't understand asking to the package manager if "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" is present gives a positive answer for ... Zalando !?! Arghhh!

Other possibility should be to integrate pieces of Xzing directly in your app.
I read many posts on this subject, all based on a different Xzing version and giving different methods and I didn't succed to get a working solution.
And obviously again, it seems that sean Owen clearly discourage this solution. What I really don't understand because in some situation, having to download a third party application while you are using your app could be vey uncomfortable and doesn't improve user experience. Well that's my point of view. I assume it even if it caused a serious downgrade in Stackoverflow !!

That's said my answer is to used Zbar. Zbar is no longer maintained on Android because its developper switched to Xzing!! well....
Anyway, it's an extremely efficient and eazy to use library and especially for the last reason, it's a high quality product.
Here I explain how to implement it:

-First download the archive https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/ZBarAndroidSDK-0.1.zip
-Then extract it of course.
You will get various directories:
 *examples, with a CameraTest activity I encourage you to integrate in Eclipse to test it and also because your will get its components
 *libs wher you will find the subdirs x86, armeab-v7a, armeabi and zbar.jar library.

Once you have imported cameraTest project in Eclipse, you should have a fully working code scanner named CameraTestActivity.

So to integrate the functionnality in your application follow these steps:

All required components are in CameraTestActivirty of course.

Copy/paste CameraTestActivity.java and CameraPreview.java from CameraTestActivity src to your proper src directory.
You would prefer to Copy/Paste the package, as you prefer.
Personnally, I renamed CameraTestActivity to QRCodeScanActivity

Copy/Paste all directoris in libs from CameraTestActivity to you proper libs directory.

Include the following part of AndroidManifest.xml in your proper AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />  Here it's as you want, it should work also on non autofocus devices
```

... your already present declarations....
     
     ....

Copy/Paste the main.xml from layout i CameraTestActivity to your proper layout directory. CameraTestActivity will force portrait orientation during the scan.
Rename this file as you want; qrcodescan.xml if you want.

You have to declare that you use zbar.jar library.
Right-click on yout application name, select properties, click on Java Build Path, then click on Add JARs and go through yourAppName\libs to select zbar.jar.

You have to change 2 or 3 little things in the code.
In QRCodeScanActivity, previously CameraTest Activity:

```
public class QRCodeScanActivity extends Activity {

    // declare a constant to use in the Intent created in your application to start he scan.
    public final static int ACTIVITY_SCAN_CODE = 33;

    .....

    // Declare an intent to respond to your activity
    Intent activityResult = new Intent();

    // Not mandatory, you can add an intermediate String to return to your application
    String textScanned;

    ......

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Put here the name you choosed in place of main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.qrcodescan);  

        ....    

        // Later you will choose if you let the TextView and the Button or not. Personnaly, I removed it to just keep the test if (barcodescanned) and its content.
        scanText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanText);

        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (barcodeScanned) {
                        barcodeScanned = false;
                        scanText.setText("Scanning...");
                        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        previewing = true;
                        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
                   }
               }
        });

    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    ...............

    PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

                Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
                barcode.setData(data);

                int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

                if (result != 0) {
                    previewing = false;
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    mCamera.stopPreview();

                    SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                    for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                        scanText.setText("barcode result " + sym.getData());
                        barcodeScanned = true;

                        // Here is what you have to add to return the result to your application
                        textScanned = sym.getData();
                        activityResult.putExtra("SCANNED", textScanned);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, activityResult);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
            }
        };
}
```

In your application now:

Somewhere where you want to start the scan from; add:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, QRCodeScanActivity.class);
     startActivityForResult(intent, QRCodeScanActivity.ACTIVITY_SCAN_CODE);
```

and you should have the necessary code to receive the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == QRCodeScanActivity.ACTIVITY_SCAN_CODE) {
         String textScanned = intent.getStringExtra("SCANNED");
         ....
    }
}
```

That should work vey very well.

Regards,